# What does 'IN' mean: 'IN your own person or IN the person of any other'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions, philosophy

[Source:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rv-4aUbZxQ) Prof Michael Sandel, *Justice: ...*, Episode 06: "MIND YOUR MOTIVE"

> 47:30 and here Kant distinguishes between persons on the one hand, and things on the other. 
>   47:38: Rational beings are persons that don't just have a relative value for us, but if anything has they have an absolute value, an intrinsic value.
>   47:50 That is, rational beings have dignity that are worthy of reverence and respect.
>   47:56: This line of reasoning leads Kant to the second formulation of the Categorical Imperative which is this:
>
> > Act in such a way that you always treated humanity,
> >     ♦ whether **in** your own person
> >     or **in** the person of any other, ♦
> >     never simply as a means, but always at    the same time,
> >     as an end.
>
> 48:21: So that's the Formula of Humanity as an End.

Why did Kant (or the German to English translator) use **in**? I know that the 1st ed. of *Critique of Pure Reason* was published in German in 1781, but I still want to rationalise or understand this use (even if it's archaic), which would've never occurred to me.
 I would've written the clause surrounded by ♦, as follows instead:

> 1. ♦ whether yourself or any other person , ♦

Footnote: I don't know which English translation Prof Sandel quoted, but please edit this if anyone does. If anyone wants to see the quote in print, see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tNoqBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=%22whether+in+your+own+person%22+routledge+guide&source=bl&ots=MI696QrqAP&sig=ygl5v54mYLfy05FnIceJHvDKpC4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2qMVVbqBAsyUNv-ng9AL&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20in%20your%20own%20person%22%20routledge%20guide&f=false) for example.

Comment: In (the position of) your person or in ( the position) of any other person.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks, but how can 'you' be `in ( the position) of any other person. `? You are you?  You can't transform into any other person?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I would suggest that if it forms the substance of the second formulation of Kant's *Categorical Imperative*, that there is a strong intellectual argument for saying that you can (transform into another person).

Comment: Looks to me like much the same "figurative preposition usage" as, for example, *"I've never met him **in** the flesh"*, *"We're acting **in** loco parentis"*, or even *"I don't wish to speak **in** anger"*.

Comment: You're treating the humanity resident *in* your person (or someone else's). The humanity, human nature, human spirit, human-ness is *in* you, and you are *of* it.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, it's the "**in**" necessary in "instantiates **in**":

---

> Avicenna's Metaphysics in Context - Page 88 Robert Wisnovsky - 2003
>
> The formal cause and final cause of my son's coming-to-be are
>   identical in number because the very same form of **humanity
>   instantiated in my son's body** at conception serves both as a formal
>   cause - as his essence, in other words

---

> Kantian ethical thought: a curricular report and annotated ... - Page
>   46 Council for Philosophical Studies - 1984
>
> He proposes that the object of respect Is the **humanity instantiated
>   in individual persons** — not the individual persons themselves. This
>   interpretation best explains the duties a person has to himself.

---

> Studies in philosophy and in the history of science: ... - Page 12
>   Richard Allen Tursman, ‎Max Harold Fisch - 1970
>
> ... that it is only natural that other communities should find
>   rational **humanity instantiated in other models**, or else to
>   admitting that Jesus was not really a man at all and hence that his
>   appearance was irrelevant to our common human problems.